# prove that $f\colon \Bbb N \times \Bbb N\to \Bbb Z,\ f(m,n)=m-n$ is surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Prove that $f\colon \Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z,\ f(m,n)=m-n$ is surjective.

Attempt:
If $m = 1$ and $n = 2 \in \Bbb N$, then $f(m,n)=m-n$.
                    $$f(1,2)=1-2 = -1 \in \Bbb Z.$$

By considering these two inputs would I prove that it is surjective?

Comment: Can you write out the definition for surjective? Could you elaborate on why you think exhibiting that there is a pair of values mapping to $-1$ satisfies it? Also, it might be relevant how you've defined $\mathbb Z$, since sometimes it is defined to be equivalence classes of $m-n$ for $m,n\in\mathbb N$, where there's little to prove.

Comment: No, considering two inputs will pretty much never show that a function is surjective; do you know the definition of surjective?

Comment: Could you add Mathjax?

Comment: @Boris That was a really rough edit; in the future, please don't just put dollar signs around things (I prefered it completely un-typeset, truthfully). You can do things like replace `x` with `\times` when it's clear the OP means Cartesian product, replace `e` with `\in` when it's clear that set membership is being denoted, etc.

Comment: ok thanks @pjs36

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\Bbb N = \{0, 1, \dotsc\}$, for every $n\ge 0$, we have $f(n,0) = n$, and $f(0,n) = -n$, so $range(f) = \Bbb Z$.

Just in case you don't think $0\in \Bbb N$:
$f(n+1,1) = n, f(1, n+1) = -n$, and $f(1,1) = 0$, so again $f$ is a surjection onto $\Bbb Z$.